# MySQL time_zone = SYSTEM not getting correct date on CURRENT_TIME

Tags: mysql, configuration, ssh, environment-variables

Via SSH I print the current date of my server, which is **correct** based on my location:

[image: SSH]

When I run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` on MySQL, I have `time_zone = SYSTEM` - which makes me think MySQL will be using the system date and time.

However, when I run `SELECT CURRENT_TIME` it returns to me a result that looks like it's in another time zone (ignore the diff in minutes due to the time I took between both snapshots):

[image: SQL]

Is there any other necessary configuration to make `CURRENT_TIME` in MySQL reflect exactly the same system date time?

Comment: Run these statements please: `SELECT NOW();` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone'` to see you session's variable value.

Comment: @JehadKeriaki, `SELECT NOW();` returned the time four hours less than the System hour and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone'` returned `SYSTEM`

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';

Comment: @RickJames, thanks, man! system_time_zone shows CST while it should be GMT-3 (my timezone). Now it's a matter of how to change it.

Comment: @AdrianoCastro - That's an Operating System question.

Comment: @RickJames, exactly. Unfortunately, I just found out after working on a solution in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, not through MySQL, but in my WHM > Server Configuration > Server Time, then clicked on **Sync Time with Time Server**.